# Samsung J5 2017 in water.

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-j5

I dropped my Samsung J5 2017 in water. I tried to turn it off straight away but it wont turn off. I cannot access the battery as it is built in. My touch screen does not work and nor do the power buttons or volume buttons. Is there anything I can do?

Comment: For recovering the data or repairing the device?  If you are trying to recover the data maybe it will semi work after a couple of days, otherwise take it somewhere that will charge $ to recover the data.  Nobody sane and truly knowledgable IME will try to repair the device. It is simple to difficult and time consuming.

Comment: Just forget it, it's gone. And be cautious next time

Answer (score 0):

Is it fully powered off currently? If not, there is luck.

METHOD 1: Requires screen lock to be None or Swipe.

1. Plug in USB cable to computer.
2. Find your phone in "This PC" in Windows, "Devices" in Linux, or download Android File Transfer ([android.com/filetransfer/)](http://android.com/filetransfer/) for Mac.
3. Copy files. If your phone does not show any storage when found it does not have a None or Swipe screen lock. Try something else.

METHOD 2: Requires USB-OTG supported mouse and keyboard (can be Bluetooth if paired before accident).

1. Plug in a keyboard and mouse (requires USB-OTG splitter, but also means your kernel has to support multiple USB ports).
2. Press the "zzz" key on the keyboard to turn screen on.
3. Use the mouse as you would a touchscreen. Remember: hold down left mouse button to right click.
4. Use some sort of wireless transfer to copy your data to a computer.

METHOD 3: Requires USB debugging to be enabled for your computer.

1. Plug your phone into your computer.
2. For Windows or Mac, download ADB tools and unzip to your user folder. For Linux, run `sudo apt-get install android-tools-fastboot android-tools-adb android-tools-adbd`.
3. Open a terminal (or command prompt) and type `adb devices`. If your device is listed, continue. If not, retry or stop.
4. Type `adb shell input keyevent 26` or `adb shell input keyevent 224` to turn on the screen.
5. To "tap", run command `adb shell input tap x y` (x and y are coordinates to tap, replace them with numbers)
6. Once your phone is unlocked, use Method 1 to transfer files.